# SDK2: Error on Timeout?

Tags: rally

In SDK I've making a request to query for a number of TestResult objects:

```
    var createParams = {
        model: 'TestCaseResult',
        autoLoad: true,
        limit: 10000,
        listeners: {
            load: this._foundTestResults,
            scope: this
        },
        context: { project: null },
        filters:    [
                        { property: 'TestSet.Tags.Name', operator: 'contains', value: release },
                        { property: 'TestCase.Method', operator: '=', value: 'Manual' },
                        { property: 'Tester.UserName', operator: '!=', value: 'XXX' }
                    ],
        fetch: ['TestCase', 'FormattedID', 'Verdict'],
        sorters: [ { property: 'Date'} ]
    };

    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', createParams);
```

This works except for early in the morning or late at night.  When it fails, I often get this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Errors' of undefined sdk.js:4
a.define.setException sdk.js:4
a.define.setException sdk.js:4
Ext.define.processResponse sdk.js:4
b.implement.callParent sdk.js:4
a.define.processResponse sdk.js:4
(anonymous function) sdk.js:4
Ext.apply.callback sdk.js:4
Ext.define.onComplete sdk.js:4
Ext.define.abort sdk.js:4
d.timeout
```

Is there an error function I need to define to avoid this?

Also, I'm wondering why this seems to happen with TestResults-- at first I thought it was because in many cases I was getting back a large number of objects, but I have also found even when the results will be few (around 100 or so) I still can get this error.

And to make matters more complicated, I am seeing break in different ways (more obscure errors) sometimes, which I think may be related to the number of items returned (when that number is in the range of 3000).

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?  This sounds like a bug in our handling of error responses from WSAPI.  I'd be curious if you upgrade to the most recent 2.0p5 release of the SDK if this issue still occurs.

Comment: Can you change the include to be sdk-debug.js and report back with the stack trace that returns?  I'll log a defect and we'll make sure this is resolved for GA.

Comment: Does it give a different stack trace than what I posted above?  I've also seen the following short stacktrace (this one run with sdk-debug, unlike the one above): Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'callback8' TestCaseResult.js:1
(anonymous function)

Comment: That is "does DEBUG give a different stack track trace than what I posted obove..."

Comment: If you are using Chrome and have the network tab open you can look directly at the response and see the results on that response. It would be pretty odd if our server responded faster in the middle of the night. Out response times are pretty consistant regardless of when you hit the system

Comment: Including sdk-debug.js will use the uncompressed version of the library so you should get more detail in your error stack trace (instead of everything saying sdk.js line 4).